# Big Query Data Regular expression

Tags: google-bigquery

I Have data in Big Query for eg: LN12_FACI_02AB and  LNR12AB23_FACI ,requirement is need to fetch data only before first( _ ) underscore.

in this case data should be like this LN12 and LNR12AB23 . From this derived data I need to remove trailing numbers so the answer should be like this LN and LNR12AB.  What would be the solution tried with regular expression not working as expected .

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
regexp_extract(col_name, r'(.*?)\d*_')
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - result is

[image]